# How to use dotfuscator in our dll

Tags: c#-4.0

How to use dotfuscator in our dll to hide my code.Please Give some guideline regarding this.

Comment: What's wrong with the dotfuscator documentation? I don't think it is obfuscated.

Comment: Which part of [the extensive documentation](http://www.preemptive.com/images/stories/dotfuscator_documentation/Dotfuscator/webframe.html), specifically, are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you.
[How to protect DLL using Dotfuscator](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=507)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the open-source Obfuscar here: http://code.google.com/p/obfuscar/
It works great, and can be placed into automated build tools.